# How can I redirect ports in Cherokee?

Tags: redirect, port, cherokee

I've installed cherokee and am very happy with it.  But now I'm wondering how I can redirect ports.  I'd like to redirect port 80 to other ports based on the hostname, as follows:

Request for `http://a.mysite.com` to `http://mysite.com:8000`
Request for `http://b.mysite.com` to `http://mysite.com:9000`

All help is appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good!  Found out myself!  :)

To redirect `http://a.mysite.com` to `http://mysite.com:8000` follow these steps in the cherokee admin web environment:

- First create a virtual server with name `a.mysite.com` and give it a document root, e.g. `/var/www/a`.
- Then link to the sources tab and create a new information source by clicking the 'plus' icon.  Enter `a.mysite.com` as nick and `mysite:8000` as connection.
- Go back to the vServers tab.  After making sure that the `a.mysite.com` server is selected check that the host match method is set to 'match nickname'.
- In the behaviour tab select the 'default' directory and in the handler tab select 'HTTP Reverse Proxy' from the handler dropdown list.  Then select 'Round Robin' as balancer in the Back-end Server section.
- In the section Assign Information Sources section select `a.mysite.com` as application server.
- Then save and restart Cherokee.

You can preform the same process for `b.mysite.com`.

Or, when your site becomes more popular, you can add more application servers to `a.mysite.com` .